# Why do unitaries act on maximally entangled states as $(U\otimes I)|\phi\rangle=(I\otimes U^T)|\phi\rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, teleportation, linear-algebra

I was reading about teleportation which had the following Bell counterpart in $N$ dimensions
$|{\phi}\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}|i\rangle\otimes|i\rangle$. The next line was
$$(U\otimes I)|\phi\rangle=\sum_{i,j=0}^{N-1}|j\rangle U_{ji}\otimes |i\rangle=\sum_{i,j=0}^{N-1}|j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle U_{ij}^T= (I\otimes U^T)|\phi\rangle$$

Here $U$ is unitary. Now I understand $(U\otimes I)=(I\otimes U)$. But the terms in between I am finding hard to grasp. Okay I understood the second part which was $|j\rangle U_{ji}$, but the next equivalence I could not understand. How did the $U_{ji}$ got shifted on the $i$.  Also should there be a $U^{\dagger}$ instead of Transpose.

Comment: $U$ doesn't even need to be a unitary, for any linear operator $A$, it's true that $(A\otimes I)|\phi\rangle=(I\otimes A^T)|\phi\rangle$ when $|\phi\rangle$ is maximally entangled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The relation $U\otimes I=I\otimes U$ is wrong, unless $U=\alpha I$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb C$.
2. You have
   $$(U\otimes I)|\Phi\rangle
   =\sum_i (U\otimes I)|i,i\rangle
   = \sum_i (U|i\rangle)\otimes |i\rangle
   = \sum_{ij} U_{ji} (|j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle)
   \\= \sum_{j} |j\rangle\otimes \left(\sum_i U_{ji}|i\rangle\right)
   = \sum_j |j\rangle\otimes(U^T |j\rangle)
   = (I\otimes U^T)|\Phi\rangle.$$

More generally, one oughts to keep in mind that an element of a tensor product space is, by definition, a sum of simple tensor products, so some $\sum_i v_i\otimes w_i$ for some $v_i,w_i\in V$. You can also have scalar coefficients, and these can be equivalently be attached to the single components of the tensor product, or to the overall tensor product:
$$\lambda(v\otimes w)=(\lambda v)\otimes w =v\otimes(\lambda w),$$
for any scalar $\lambda$ and $v,w\in V$. The reason the scalar products can be "carried outside" as in this equation is that tensor product are by definition bilinear.

Comment: In general for $U$ will it always be $U^T$? or should it be $U^{\dagger}$. For instance i have a $Y$ gate then then $Y^T$ wont work

Comment: @Upstart it is the transpose. What do you mean by $Y^T$ won't work? Note that if $U=U^*$ then $U^T=\overline{U}$ where $\overline{U}$ is the complex conjugate and so $U$ would go to $\overline{U}$ on the other side.

Comment: That is what I meant. Writing just $U^T$ might not be right. It should be $\bar{U}$.

Comment: @Upstart no, the transpose is correct, not the complex conjugate, as proved in the answer